# Не могу связаться с термо-принтером через Bluetooth. Android

Tags: java, android, 1с, print

Здравствуйте. Есть [термо-принтер](http://www.posnet.com.pl/Produkty-POSNET/Urzadzenia-fiskalne/Drukarki-fiskalne/mobilne/Posnet-Temo-HS-EJ) для печати билетов.
На android пишется приложение которое будет служить драйвером между приложение 1C и данным принтером. Принтер будет связываться с телефоном по Bluetooth.
Соединение с принтером делал по примеру с этого [сайта](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). На принтере загорается индикатор при соединение, но при передачи команды ничего не происходит. При чтение потока приложение зависает.
Возможно кто-то уже делал что-то подобное и сможет подсказать.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: лучше задавайте конкретный вопрос. что написали? какая ошибка вываливается?

Comment: Суть в том при отправке команды ошибки нет. А при чтении приложение висит, пока не закроешь отладку. К принтеру конектился по инструкции и отправляю команду с доков.

Comment: Что вы хотите от сообщества? Чтоб мы телепатическими каналами связи соединились с вашим компом и посмотрели ваш код и ошибки?

Comment: [Ссылка на GitHub](https://github.com/maksymmykytuk/POSNET.git).

Comment: после `mmOutStream.write(bytes);` необходимо вызывать `mmOutStream.flush();`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поставить приложение PrintShare, и если с ним заведется то можно использовать их SDK - http://www.printershare.com/help-android-integration.sdf

Comment: PrintShare его не видит.